# else if javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a simple function that is supposed to prompt the user for the company name, followed by a confirmation message box that asks the user "Would you like to order a Web Design package today?" The problem is with my 'if' and 'else if' statements. The 'if' statement should show an alert box "Thank you for your order" when the user clicks 'OK'; and an 'else if' statement that should show an alert box "We appreciate your time" when the user clicks 'Cancel'. The function is called by an onClick script. The prompt and confirmation boxes appear but I can't figure out why my if and else if boxes do not appear. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<SCRIPT language = "Javascript">

function submitOrder() {

var companyName = prompt("Please enter company name.", "")

var willOrderPackage = confirm("Would you like to order a Web Design package today?")

if (willOrderPackage == "true") {
   alert("Thank you for your order.")

}else if{
   alert("We appreciate your time.")
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: `if (thisPartIsAlwaysNeeded) ..`; but perhaps just use `else` *without* an "if"?

Comment: Don't want to be rude, but you really should learn how to write code. First of all, that javascript looks like it was written in the 90's (upper case tag names, capitalized language name, no ending semicolon etc). Secondly, comparing a boolean value with a string 'true' clearly shows a lack of understanding of fundamentals. This is even more enforced with the fact that you left the condition for the second `if` statement.

Comment: @Christian I don't use semi-colons. I find them frivolous. (And please have a *good argument* before entering into a debate on why not using semi-colons is "bad" or "shows lack of understanding".) Also, none of the conventions *inside* the script element look "bad". I agree with the "true" bit or the dated container or invalid syntax ..

Comment: @pst Closing semicolons ensure there are no ambiguous line endings. There is a reason we end sentences with a period ;). My argument holds, see my answer for the reasons.

Comment: I agree with @Christian that there are current best practices that are not being followed. Semicolons tend to be a best practice but are also personal preference even though they used to cause errors in old IE if done wrong. If you're working with more than one developer then typically it's best to follow certain best practices.

Comment: @Christian Flip it around and consider this: There is no such thing as an ambiguous *line ending* in JavaScript, only an ambiguous *line beginning*. This how ASI works: by trying to complete an expression on the next line (and automatically inserting a semi-colon if it cannot). Thus, avoiding starting a line with `(` (write as `;(`), `[` (avoid, useless construct) or operator (avoid, useless construct) removes all "ambiguity".

Comment: . Oh my god, so the problem was in the way a line starts?!?!. I never knew. Didn't know we add periods to the beginning of sentences. Hey, I'll even start now

Comment: @Christian I fail to see how that applies. I have been using my simple rules for years now. I have had exactly one issue. Once. The first time I wrote a like like `(function ..` where ASI didn't work as I epxected. Ever since then I have used `;(function ..`. Number of issues since then: 0.

Comment: Sarcasm aside, I understand the technicality of your point, but that does not answer for the shortcoming in syntax. If languages were meant to be nearer to computers than humans, we would have stuck to assembler. Just because you used bad practice to fix an even worse one doesn't mean it's good.

Comment: @Christian Your last "argument" is flawed. It assumes that JavaScript syntax is somehow "more to human" than Haskell or SML or other languages that do not require semi-colons.

Comment: `"use strict";` mode enforces semicolons.

Comment: @arxanas Ahh. Nabbits. I can't argue against that :(

Comment: @arxanas As a tribute to `pst`, I'm gonna use that in all my script from now on. Muahahaha.

Comment: take it easy on tracie, i've seen worse code

Comment: @ClickUpvote true, didn't want to cause an uproar over this. It's always difficult to tell people to "read the manual" nicely. :(

Comment: _"Don't want to be rude,"_ - but somehow, @Christian, you managed to overcome your distaste and point out "problems" that aren't actually errors. Uppercase tagnames are valid. The "missing" semicolons are not actually an error: personally I _do_ use semicolons on every line, but only to avoid having to keep explaining ASI to workmates who don't understand it. _"but you really should learn how to write code"_ - Isn't that what Tracie is doing here? _"clearly shows a lack of understanding of fundamentals"_ - Like you're doing in insisting that semicolons are required?

Comment: @nnnnnn I did not insist that semicolons are required, is it too hard to read comments nowadays? Did you even see my answer below? I correct 3 different errors...the rest are recommendations. I'm sure I'd have gathered more points if I simply answered questions roboticaly like some people do. That's called rep-whoring for a reason. Inserting `if`s in inappropriate places, leaving out curly brackets, etc is a clear lack of fundamental programming knowledge. The rest are recommendations.

Comment: @nnnnnn My answer corrected all of the above code's issues, and how much points does it get? ZERO. Why? Because I took it upon me to advise a fellow developer. Obviously people want to hear how great they are....heck everyone's quick to point out that "semicolons are an excuse to ASI" and all that bullshit, yet no one took the liberty to explain why semicolons *should* be there. That is, except **me**. But obviously, it's easy to criticize answers, especially when it concerns opposing opinion. Here's a challenge, go criticize questions with no answers at all. At least, it could be constructive

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh and by the way, when you decide to quote someone, be sure to actually *quote someone*, not pick words from a conversation like a dictionary.

Comment: @Christian - My comment was concerned with your original comment above, not your answer. If you'd used a more friendly tone, perhaps something like "These aren't actually causing your error, but there are some things in your code that could be improved with regard to current best practices...", then I likely wouldn't have objected and may even have given a +1 (though we will have to agree to disagree about semicolons). Since you mention your answer: if you'd made it clear which changes were necessary and which were recommendations I might've upvoted it (but I didn't downvote).

Comment: P.S. @Christian, Regarding the _phrases_ I quoted, I certainly didn't intend to make it sound like you'd said something you didn't - the phrases I quoted related directly to the points I made.

Comment: Regarding the my original comment, it's clear what is optional and what not. Please realize that it was intended as a comment, not as an answer. Regarding my answer, if you cared so much, you could have edited it, or at least pointed out your concerns. That said, there's still the fact that if someone knew the fundamentals, one wouldn't have to mention what is necessary and what is not.

Answer (score 15):

There are actually two different if..else constructs. The first is a simple if-else:

```
if ( condition ) {
   // Do stuff if condition is true
} else {
   // Do stuff if condition is not true
}
```

The next is an if-else-if:

```
if ( condition ) {
   // Do stuff if condition is true
} else if ( differentCondition ) {
   // Do stuff if differentCondition is true
} else {
   // Do stuff if neither condition nor differentCondition is true
}
```

You can also use else-if as many times as you like, e.g.:

```
if ( condition ) {
   // Do stuff
} else if ( condition2 ) {
   // etc
} else if ( condition3 ) {
   // etc
} else if ( condition4 ) {
   // etc
} else {
   // etc
}
```

And every part of an if..else is optional, except for the initial if block. So if you don't want to do anything if `condition` is not true, you can just omit the else block entirely:

```
if ( condition ) {
   // do stuff if condition is true
}
```

HTH

Going beyond your question for a moment, the expression being evaluated in your if statement's condition is a bit wibbly-wobbly.

willOrderPackage will always be `true` or `false`, but it's important to note that `true` and `"true"` or `false` and `"false"` are different. The first is boolean, the second is a string.

So, your if statement should be asking:

```
if ( willOrderPackage == true ) {
```

Even better than that, when you evaluate an expression in an if statement, there's an implied `== true` at the end of it which is invisible. For instance:

```
if ( willOrderPackage == true ) {
```

would be interpreted as :

```
if ( (willOrderPackage == true) == true )
```

The benefit of this is that you can actually omit the whole `== true` bit from your code, so you can just write:

```
if ( willOrderPackage ) {
```

And effectively you're still saying "if willOrderPackage is true"

Hope that helps clear up a few things for you!

Answer (score 7):

your `else if` has no condition, use `else`

as stated

```
if (willOrderPackage == "true") {
alert("Thank you for your order.")
```

is wrong: willOrderPackage is a boolean so it can be

```
(willOrderPackage == true)
```

or even better

```
(willOrderPackage)
```

Comment: `willOrderPackage` is also a Boolean so it shouldn't be compared to `"true"`.

Comment: `if attack = "true" launchNukes()`

Comment: @TracieRichardson Please choose a correct answer if you are happy with one/it solved your problem

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Actually the first response was correct. I used 'else' since the 'else if' had no condition. It worked! I'm in a JavaScript 101 class and this is very very basic stuff I'm learning just to get my feet wet.

Comment: No problem, to be honest I thought that was the main issue you were looking for and that was easiest to miss, a small syntax error that seems so insignificant, but technically the other part needed fixing too so thought best to add it in. If you want to accept an answer as correct it has a tick below the up and down arrows that you need to click. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

also it's better to use :

```
if (willOrderPackage) {
```

instead of :

```
if (willOrderPackage == "true") {
```

Comment: @pst, but it is a change that should also be made.

Comment: @jfriend00 I completely agree. I didn't read this as a "comment" post..

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
if (willOrderPackage) {
   alert("Thank you for your order.")

}else{
   alert("We appreciate your time.")
}
```

Comment: +1 - you got both recommended fixes.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's properly done:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function submitOrder() {
    var companyName = prompt("Please enter company name.", "");
    var willOrderPackage = confirm("Would you like to order a Web Design package today?");

    if (willOrderPackage) {
        alert("Thank you for your order.");
    }else{
        alert("We appreciate your time.");
    }
}

</script>
```

Things I did:

- modernized coding style
- switched to type attribute instead of language
- added semicolons on each ending line
- removed redundant `if` keyword
- added a closing curly bracket which was originally missing
- removed comparison with a string true, comparison with boolean values do not need this

Comment: That's not how it's properly done. Why are you saying `if(willOrderPackage == "true")`? First of all, you should be using the `===` operator when making strict comparisons. In addition, there's no need because you just check to see `if(willOrderPackage)`.

Comment: There was no reason to add semi-colons.

Comment: @pst Honestly, it's fine that you don't like the use of semi-colons. I don't agree with it, but I'm not going to argue against it because the markers of javascript obviously had some not-so-smart thoughts and this is how the language is now. Regardless, when teaching the language, it's best to teach best practices. There are tons of moments where a semi-colon is necessary, and teaching that to a beginner is vital.

Comment: @Nile That was a copy mistake on my part, as I already said in my earlier comment, comparison with a string true is unnecessary. Thing is, there were so many issues with the code, I forgot removing that part there!

Comment: @pst Try minify-ing semicolon-less javascript, and you'll see why they're necessary.

Comment: @Christian Only if using a **broken** minifier. That is not my problem. That is a problem with **broken** tools. Just say `"use strict;"` already ..

Comment: I wrote that example before the other guy mentioned strict. Anyway, think of it this way, the minifier would end up fixing broken code if it had to add semicolons to minify the code while keeping it runnable ;).