# Why does the score not equal 0 when I roll a 1?

Tags: javascript, probability, dice

So I'm making a dice game where if either ofd the dice roll a 1, the score is 1, but I can't seem to make that work. I believe everything else it ok.

```
    var die1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6 + 1);
    var die2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6 + 1);
    var score;
    if (die1 === 1 || die2 === 1){
        score === 0;
       } 
    if (die1 !== 1 || die2 !== 1){
            score = die1 + die2;

    }
    console.log("You rolled a "+die1+" and a "+die2+" for a score of "+score);
```

Comment: I think you need to replace 'score === 0;' with 'score = 0;' on line 4.

Comment: you have put `score === 0` should be `score = 0` *edit* too slow..

Comment: `"if either of the dice roll a 1, the score is 1"` But your code is (incorrectly, as mentioned by Ruslan) attempting to set it to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you don't set `score` to 0. Change `score === 0` to `score = 0`.

Second, your second `if` is still evaluated. Try making it an `else if`:

```
if (die1 === 1 || die2 === 1){
    score = 0;
   } 
else if ...
```

Comment: +1. but based on what he's trying to do, I would get rid of the second if altogether and just change it to an else. he's using `die1 != 1 || die2 != 1` i believe he's just trying to say `else` ..

Comment: awesome! Making it an else if worked, but why is that? Just for future reference

Comment: @JackWalsh You don't need to test your logic twice, once as "true" and again inverted. That's what the else is for.

Comment: The `else` in the `else if` means "if the previous condition wasn't true, then evaluate this". When it isn't there, the first `if` is evaluated (and your score theoretically set) then the second `if` is evaluated and your score is overwritten.

Comment: Let's look at your code: `if (die1 === 1 || die2 === 2)` .. this evaluates to if either of them are 1 then do what's in the { } .. because there's no else, no matter if your first evaluates true, you're running the second if statement `if (die1 != 1 || die2 != 1) { score = die1 + die2 }` as well .. so because only one of your die are randomly 1, this will also evaluate true and add your score together.

Answer (score 1):

Tying together all of the great suggestions here:

```
if (die1 === 1 || die2 === 1) {
    score = 1;                // "if either of the dice roll a 1, the score is 1"
                              // Also, use = for assignment, not == or ===
} 
else {                        // No need to check the inverse - just use else
    score = die1 + die2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (die1 === 1 || die2 === 1) {
    score = 1;                // You are not comparing you are assigning here
} 
else if ...               // Better use else if than using if as in your code
```

For more information :-

[else if javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291092/else-if-javascript)