# Javascript elseif/if else help needed

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm quite new to coding and I've never understood what's the proper way to do the following:

```
if (something == true) {
    DoSomething();
} else {
    if (something2 == true) {
        DoSomething2();
    }
    DoSomethingAnyways();
}
```

I've heard using `else if` is the right way to do this, but how can I execute the `DoSomethingAnyways();` if I use `else if`?

Basically what I'm asking is how can I write this using else if and have the exact same effect?

```
if (something == true) {
    DoSomething();
} else if (something2 == true) {
    DoSomething2();
    DoSomethingAnyways(); //<-- Where do I put this line of code?
}
```

Comment: Do you want `DoSomethingAnyways` to fire regardless of which path the code takes in the IF statement? If so, just put it after the entire IF/ELSE block

Comment: @datman123 May be interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291092/else-if-javascript

Comment: @lux No, it should only execute in the else path.

Comment: Small sidenote: you don't need the `==true` part, you can just `if(something){}`

Comment: @KimGysen: Not necessarily. `if(something) {` and `if(something==true) {` can have different meaning depending on the type of `something`.

Comment: @datman123: No, you can't  put `DoSomethingAlways()` behind a condition and have it run irrespective of the result of that condition.

Comment: @squint true for any truthy value indeed. Still, `==true` seems a bit redundant here.

Comment: @KimGysen: Yeah, it's pretty unusual to use `==true` since it forces you to remember all the weird type coersion rules.

Comment: Though if you were using `===` instead of `==`, you could accomplish it with a `switch` statement. `switch(true) { case something: DoSomething(); break; case something2: DoSomething2(); default: DoSomethingAlways(); }` Notice that the second `case` falls through to the `default`.

Comment: I kind of feel like this question should explain why the DoSomethingAnyways(); can not fall outside the if/then/else block.  If the question really is "Is there a 'finally' block to if/then/else" than the answer is just "no".  Otherwise some of the posters below are correct in that the thing to do is just move the DoSomethingAnyways(); outside the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you've done it. `else if` is for cases like this:

```
if (foo) {
  doSomething()
}
if (!foo && bar) {
  doSomethingElse()
}
if (!foo && !bar) {
  nothingWorked()
}
```

which works the same as this:

```
if (foo) {
  doSomething()
} else if (bar) {
  doSomethingElse()
} else {
  nothingWorked()
}
```

However your example doesn't fit this pattern.

See also [part of the jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/prop.js#L42). Not quite the same, but similar.

Answer (score 3):

Under the assumption that you want

- DoSomething() to be called if "something" is true,
- DoSomething2() to be called if "something2" is true but "something" isn't, and
- DoSomethingAnyways() to be called if "something" is false, regardless of "something2"

then your code is the way to go.

```
if (something == true) {
    DoSomething();
} else {
    if (something2 == true) {
        DoSomething2();
    }
    DoSomethingAnyways();
}
```

**Using "Else If"**

If you don't want to use nested ifs, you could write this, which has the same effect as your original code:

```
if (something == true) {
    DoSomething();
} else if (something2 == true) {
    DoSomething2();
    DoSomethingAnyways();
} else {
    DoSomethingAnyways();
}
```

However this adds complexity when it comes to maintenance. Imagine that in a few months, you need to add code to perform an action before DoSomethingAnyways(). You potentially have to maintain two branches - the "else if" and the "else" branch - making your code more and more complex. You might forget about updating one branch, because the dependency is no longer obvious - and that introduces a bug.

**Code Complexity**

It's true that nesting ifs makes your code harder to read - and there is a metric for that: the cyclomatic complexity (independent paths through your code). However, in your case the cyclomatic complexity is the same, whether you use else-ifs or the else with the nested if - you have 3 independent paths. Generally you should consider splitting up your code once you reach 10, so you'd still be far away from that. In this case, the cyclomatic complexity is low, and your code is easy to grasp, so I wouldn't worry about it.

I personally find your original code "prettier" than an else-if/else, because it describes the dependency better (you call "DoSomethingAnyways()" regardless of whether something2 is true, but you do the whole DoSomething2/DoSomethingAnyways only if something is false).

**Refactor the else branch info a function**

If you are worried about nesting ifs too much, refactor the else branch info a new function:

```
if (something == true) {
    DoSomething();
} else {
    DoSomething3(something2);
}

function DoSomething3(something2) {
    if (something2 == true) {
        DoSomething2();
    }
    DoSomethingAnyways();
}
```

There is a small overhead for calling functions, so I wouldn't take it to the extreme - use your own judgement. If you think "oh I wonder if I'm still going to get that in a year", then you should probably reduce complexity (and document your work, using comments).

Either way you do it - with the else and the nested if, or the function - both fragments of code you'll read in months, and likely still grasp the dependency quickly, and you don't run into the risk of forgetting to update one branch when you change your code in future.

Comment: I thought the same too, that my original code is good, but afterwards I've seen a lot of people complaining that doing `else { if` instead of `else if {` is weird and makes messy code. Is there really any difference or is it just a preference thing? Should I just stick with whatever works / looks easy to read enough

Comment: @datman123 generally you want to avoid nesting `if`s because it makes the code harder to read the more you nest them. One level won't matter too much so do whatever you find to be the most readable / maintainable.

Comment: Coming back to this question after a while, there's one more thing that could have been done, and that I could have suggested: refactor the else branch into a function. This improves readability, and maintainability. Duplicating the "DoSomethingAnyways" is definitely poor style - especially because you're just bound to run into a bug where you updated the "else if" branch but not the "else" one. So you can either do what the OP suggested, or, if you're worried about nesting too much, just place everything into a new function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `DoSomethingAnyways()` to fire only if `DoSomething()` doesn't fire and not care whether or not `DoSomething2()` will fire than could rewrite your first example like this:

```
if (something == true) {
    DoSomething();
} else if (something2 == true) {
    DoSomething2();
}

if(something != true){
    DoSomethingAnyways();
}
```

you can also take out `==` and `!=` if you are relying on truthy values and write it like this:

```
if (something) {
    DoSomething();
} else if (something2) {
    DoSomething2();
}

if(!something){
    DoSomethingAnyways();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want DoSomethingAnyways() to get always fired you can put it after if else like this:

```
if (something == true) {
    DoSomething();
} else if (something2 == true) {
    DoSomething2();

}
 DoSomethingAnyways();
```

Comment: I dont think this should be downvoted.  The first sentence of the was
"I'm quite new to coding and I've never understood what's the proper way to do the following:"  and this is the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

A short and simpler approach would be to separate `something2` and `something`'s logic.

```
something ? DoSomething() : DoSomethingAnyway();

if (something2) {
  DoSomething2();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are **on a method only with these if else blocks**, you could write like this (i think this solution is cleaner):

```
void method() {
    if (something == true) {
        DoSomething();
        return;
    }

    if (something2 == true) {
        DoSomething2();
    }

    DoSomethingAnyways();
}
```

Otherwise, if you want DoSomethingAnyways() to be ran really **anyways, even if DoSomething2() throws an Exception**, it could be written as a try/finally block:

```
if (something == true) {
    DoSomething();
}

try {
    if (something2 == true) {
        DoSomething2();
    }
} finally {
    DoSomethingAnyways();
}
```

Anyway, I agree with **gcampbell**, your first code sounds fine for yuor case.