# Get one jQuery media query to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three CSS `@media` queries and I need to run some JavaScript to measure the height of a div and move a second div on some screen sizes. The issue is that all of my queries are applying, obviously because they all return true.  How can I adjust this so that only one of the conditionals fire in jQuery, similarly to CSS?

```
//Responsive Adjustments
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).resize(function () {
    console.log($(window).width());
    
    if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
      console.log ('tab land');
    }

    if ($(window).width() <= 980) {
      console.log ('tab port');
    }

    if ($(window).width() <= 479) {
      console.log ('phone port');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [else if javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291092/else-if-javascript)

Comment: @FabianS. - I tried else if statements, but since the first was true, it never got to the others.

Comment: @Iisrael your lowest width if must be first. It must be small > large for it to work.

Comment: @GoldenretriverYT - Ahh, yes, that makes much more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `else if` and check from mobile upwards:

```js
//Responsive Adjustments
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    console.log($(window).width());

    if ($(window).width() <= 479) {
      console.log('phone port');
    } else if ($(window).width() <= 980) {
      console.log('tab port');
    } else if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
      console.log('tab land');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, that does it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust your conditions:

```js
//Responsive Adjustments
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    console.log($(window).width());

    if ($(window).width() <= 1024 && $(window).width() > 980) {
      console.log('tab land');
    }

    if ($(window).width() <= 980 && $(window).width() > 479) {
      console.log('tab port');
    }

    if ($(window).width() <= 479) {
      console.log('phone port');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```